# OpenGL texture wrap ignored when using glBindImageTexture

Tags: opengl

I am using a GL_R32F format texture to pass a 2D array of floats to an OpenGL shader.  I want the texture to be wrap around so I specify the GL_REPEAT, but it seems to be ignored for textures I create with glBindImageTexture.  If I try and access a pixel value beyond the image edge in the shader it just returns 0 and does not wrap around.  This is the code I am using...

```
      glGenTextures(1,@imagetexture1);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,imagetexture1);
      glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
      glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
      setlength(arrayvalues,imwidth*imheight);
      for loop:=0 to imwidth*imheight-1 do arrayvalues[loop]:=random;
      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, imwidth, imheight, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, arrayvalues);
      setlength(arrayvalues,0);
      glBindImageTexture( 1,                  //unit
                          imagetexture1,      //texture
                          0,                  //level
                          false,              //layered
                          0,                  //layer
                          GL_READ_WRITE,      //access
                          GL_R32F);           //format
```

The GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER and GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER do work, it is just the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP parameters that get ignored.  Is there some other way I am supposed to declare wrap when using glBindImageTexture?

Comment: "*The GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER and GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER do work*" No, they don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping behavior (and min/mag modes for that matter) only make sense when accessing a texture. When accessing an image, those things don't exist. You are fetching a pixel of data from a specific piece of the image. If you try to access outside of the range of the image, then you get undefined behavior, exactly as would happen if you access outside of the bounds of an array.